# How to add default data to a new Excel worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table on the first worksheet of an MS Excel file. If I create a new worksheet, I would like to populate it with certain rows and columns from the table in the first worksheet.

To be specific, if I have the following table in the first worksheet:

```
________________________________________________________
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 | Header 5 |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

and then I click on a new worksheet, I should have the following automatically appear:

```
__________________________________
| Header 1 | Header 4 | Header 5 |
----------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
----------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
----------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
----------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
----------------------------------
|   Data   |   Data   |   Data   |
----------------------------------
```

Any pointers to how I should go about achieving this? I would like to avoid creating macros as I am not familiar with programming in VB. But if that is the only option, I am willing to explore it.

Comment: I'm confused, how would the code know what sheet to get data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use macros. In the `ThisWorkbook` (see snapshot), paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> This is where you set the input sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    '~~> the range that you need to replicate
    ws.Range("A1:A5,D1:E5").Copy

    '~~> I am doing paste special values
    '~~> Change it to `xlPasteAll` if you need formats to be copied as well
    Sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

Let's say you have this data in Sheet1.

[image]

Now every time a sheet is added, the data will be copied to a new sheet.

[image]

The Code has to be pasted here

[image]

**NOTE**:

The biggest drawback of this method is that you will loose your undo list.

Comment: Siddharth: Thank you for the snippet. That really works! Would you also know how I could marry the cells created in the new worksheet to the original ones so that if I change anything in the original, it updates across all the worksheets?

Comment: Instead of doing a paste, you will have to then create formula which will refer to those cells

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid macros you will find a solution in the combination of Index, Match and Row functions.

```
=Match(ColumHeader2,ColumHeaders1,0)
```

will give you the column in the Sheet1

```
=Index(Sheet1!A1,Row(Sheet2!CellRef),Match(ColumHeader2,ColumHeaders1,0))
```

gives you the value to be transposed to Sheet 2

`CellRef = address` of the cell where you want the data to be transposed.

The formula in `sheet2!A2` then looks like:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$F$11,ROW(Sheet2!A2),MATCH(A$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1;0))
```

`Sheet1!$A$1:$F$11` = data range including headers in sheet1

`Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1` = headers range in sheet1

Just copy the formula to all cells in sheet2 that might contain transposed values.